# MySQL JOIN sub query with custom ON clause

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(customJoin.time))
FROM journey
JOIN journey_code ON journey_code.journey = journey.id
JOIN journey_day ON journey_day.journey = journey.id
JOIN pattern ON pattern.id = journey.pattern
JOIN (
    SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(time)) AS time
    FROM pattern_link
    WHERE /* how can I tell MySQL to use the ON pattern.section value here? */
    ) customJoin ON pattern_link.section = pattern.section
JOIN service ON service.id = journey.service AND NOW() BETWEEN service.date_start AND service.date_end 
JOIN `line` ON line.service = service.id 
JOIN operator ON operator.id = service.operator
WHERE journey_code.code = '2108'
AND operator.code = "BLV"
AND `line`.name = "X4"
AND journey_day.day = 1
LIMIT 1
```

The aim of the SQL above is to select the total time based on the `JOIN` value of the pattern's section (directly above in SQL query).

I can't seem to get this working. I need to pass the `ON` clause value into the `WHERE` clause inside the `JOIN`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you use aggregation for this:

```
JOIN (
    SELECT pattern_link.section, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(time)) AS time
    FROM pattern_link
    GROUP BY pattern_link.section
    ) pl ON pl.section = pattern.section
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Will accept as soon as timer is up.